# Not able to write csv file by taking data from kafka topic in spark Streaming with scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to read data from Kafka topic with the below code:

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sparkSession = createSparkSession()
    val df = sparkSession.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092").option("subscribe", "test").option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()
    val df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

    df1.writeStream.format("parquet").option("format","append").option("checkpointLocation", "/home/krishna/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/delete").option("path", "/home/krishna/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/abc").option("truncate", "false").outputMode("append").start()
  }
}
```

When I am using the below line:

```scala
df1.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .option("truncate","false")
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

then output will be displayed on the console.

But the problem is when I am replacing above line below line of code:

```scala
df1.writeStream
  .format("csv")
  .option("format","append")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/krishna/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/delete")
  .option("path", "/home/krishna/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/abc")
  .option("truncate", "false")
  .outputMode("append")
  .start()
```

Then the output is not saved in a CSV format. Only abc folder is created and the metadata folder is created inside it but there is no CSV file in it.

I am not able to understand that if the o/p is successfully displayed on a console then why it is not saved in file in the form of csv, parquet or text.
Sample output:

```sh
------------------
| key  | value   |
------------------
| null | abc     |
| null | 123     |
|-----------------
```

Dependencies:

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: .option("truncate", "false") is for console sink you have used for csv sink isnt it ?

Comment: I have also tried the above code without using this option. but the above code is not able to save the data into CSV, also not displaying any error.

Comment: you are using df for console and df1 for csv may be this is difference have you checked it ?

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram I updated the above question it was only spelling mistake

Comment: When I used read and write instead of readstream and writestream. Then this code had worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.writeStream
.outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
.format("csv")
.option("checkpointLocation", "/home/krishna/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/delete")
.option("path", "/home/krishna/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/abc/")
.start()
```

you can use format type as: **com.databricks.spark.csv**

Comment: Same as i posted in question, not working

Answer (score 0):

in console you are using `df` and for csv you are using `df1`.

Most of the code looks fine for me.

try this.

```
df.writeStream 
    .format("csv")
    .option("format", "append")
    .trigger(processingTime = "5 seconds")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/krishna/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/delete")
.option("path", "/home/krishna/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/abc")
    .outputMode("append")
    .start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the below code with Spark 2.4.5 and it produces the csv files as required:

```scala
 val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("myAppName")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  val df = sparkSession.readStream
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("subscribe", "test")
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .load()

  val df1 = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

  df1.writeStream
    .format("csv")
    .outputMode("append")
    .option("set", ",")
    .option("checkpointLocation", "/home/krishna/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/delete")
    .option("path", "/home/krishna/Downloads/kafka_2.12-2.0.0/abc.csv")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

This code will create a folder named `abc.csv`. Depending on the parallelism of your Sparksession (configurable by `spark.default.parallelism`) you will find as many csv files as you have partitions. The number of files reflects the number of partitions in the DataFrame at the time it is written out. If you would repartition it before then, you would end up with a different number of files.

In my case the partition was `2` so I got this output in the corresponding folder:

```sh
> ~/abc.csv$ ll
total 28
drwxrwxr-x  3 x x 4096 Apr 18 17:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 50 x x 4096 Apr 18 17:01 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 x x    8 Apr 18 17:00 part-00000-77250d4a-e3af-46ef-b572-5476a3d075dd-c000.csv
-rw-r--r--  1 x x    4 Apr 18 17:00 part-00000-82a76a8c-5977-4891-be36-1c2dc6837fb1-c000.csv
```

Comment: When I used read and write instead of readstream and writestream. Then this code had worked.

Comment: The code is not a problem as it runs fine on my machine. I guess you have issues with dependencies (and maybe conflicts). As mentioned, I have tested the code and it is running fine. Maybe, you can shed some light on *what* is not working? Stating that "something is not working" usually nevery leads to a solution.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question header, My code is not able to write CSV file. I tried with your code also, it is not able to CSV file. You can see dependencies in a question description.

Comment: Again, if you are just saying "my code is not able to write CSV file" but not saying what error/excpetion you get or what you are observing, it is not possible to figure out what your problem is.

Comment: Also, how do you submit/run this spark job? It looks like the pom file has some libraries stated as "provided" so you need to take care of that.

Comment: no exception, Code is running successfully. The only problem it is not able to write in CSV as I mentioned.

Comment: @MichaelHeil could you please share your pom.xml to review how's your config setup? Usually you want to share your entire solution to be considered as possible answer to a question that is well described.